# Escaped quotes in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am unable to create a dataframe which has escaped quotes when using [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html).
 (Note: R's `read.csv` works as expected.)

#### My code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('data.csv')
#error!
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 4, saw 3
```

#### data.csv

```
SEARCH_TERM,ACTUAL_URL
"bra tv bord","http://www.ikea.com/se/sv/catalog/categories/departments/living_room/10475/?se%7cps%7cnonbranded%7cvardagsrum%7cgoogle%7ctv_bord"
"tv på hjul","http://www.ikea.com/se/sv/catalog/categories/departments/living_room/10475/?se%7cps%7cnonbranded%7cvardagsrum%7cgoogle%7ctv_bord"
"SLAGBORD, \"Bergslagen\", IKEA:s 1700-tals serie","http://www.ikea.com/se/sv/catalog/categories/departments/living_room/10475/?se%7cps%7cnonbranded%7cvardagsrum%7cgoogle%7ctv_bord"
```

How can I read this csv and avoid this error?

*My guess is that pandas is using some regular expressions which cannot handle the ambiguity and trips on the third row, or more specifically: `\"Bergslagen\"`.*

Comment: That's weird, [Wes has just completely rewritten `read_csv`](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=635) so perhaps this will no longer be the case in the upcoming `0.10` release.

Comment: I do use the development 0.10 version. Maybe I should upgrade again.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It does work, but you have to indicate the escape character for the embedded quotes:

```
In [1]: data = '''SEARCH_TERM,ACTUAL_URL
"bra tv bord","http://www.ikea.com/se/sv/catalog/categories/departments/living_room/10475/?se%7cps%7cnonbranded%7cvardagsrum%7cgoogle%7ctv_bord"
"tv p\xc3\xa5 hjul","http://www.ikea.com/se/sv/catalog/categories/departments/living_room/10475/?se%7cps%7cnonbranded%7cvardagsrum%7cgoogle%7ctv_bord"
"SLAGBORD, \\"Bergslagen\\", IKEA:s 1700-tals serie","http://www.ikea.com/se/sv/catalog/categories/departments/living_room/10475/?se%7cps%7cnonbranded%7cvardagsrum%7cgoogle%7ctv_bord"'''

In [2]: df = read_csv(StringIO(data), escapechar='\\', encoding='utf-8')

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
                                      SEARCH_TERM                                         ACTUAL_URL
0                                     bra tv bord  http://www.ikea.com/se/sv/catalog/categories/d...
1                                      tv på hjul  http://www.ikea.com/se/sv/catalog/categories/d...
2  SLAGBORD, "Bergslagen", IKEA:s 1700-tals serie  http://www.ikea.com/se/sv/catalog/categories/d...
```

*see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/4260416).*

Comment: Any way to make this work when your escape for the quote character is the quote? (This is SAS CSV output, so a line with returns and quotes may have 3 double quotes in a row, or two if they aren't at the beginning or ending of the column)