# Parse csv with quotes and commas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, escaping, double-quotes

I am trying to read a csv in Pandas (through the `read_csv` function), where the second attribute `text` contains a string encapsulated with double quotes. Some examples contain more quotes inside the string, which are escaped, e.g. `"He said \"Okay, I will\" but I doubt it"`.

```
e.g. 
  id, text
   0, "random text"
   1, "He said \"Okay, I will\" but I doubt it"
```

Whenever I run the `read_csv` function, I get the error `CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 1, saw 3`. This is because the comma inside the substring `\"Okay, I will\"` is being acknowledged as a separator, when it's not.

How can I fix this?

---

**Edit**

I found the solution on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824840/escaped-quotes-in-pandas-read-csv). All I gotta do is add 2 attributes to `read_csv`: `pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', escapechar='\\', encoding='utf-8')`. It's working fine now.

Comment: Did you make the csv file? Usually there are escape characters before commas that do not separate elements. I believe the standard escape character is `"` so maybe `"He said "Okay", I will" but I doubt it"` would work, but that's usually a setting in your parser too.

Comment: @Reedinationer Yes, it was a manual arff to csv conversion. I forgot to mention in the OP that the quotes are escaped. I found a solution on another post which I added to the OP.

Comment: if that is the solution it is common practice to post your own answer to your own question and then accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824840/escaped-quotes-in-pandas-read-csv). All I gotta do is add 2 attributes to `read_csv`: `pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', escapechar='\\', encoding='utf-8')`. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

The file you show is incorrect. Quotes inside quoted fields are supposed to be doubled. And no space should occur after the delimiter. It should be:

```
id,text
0,"random text"
1,"He said ""Okay, I will"" but I doubt it"
```

Comment: There's no space after the delimiter, I manually inserted the examples and misplaced them. Anyway, I rewrote the question because I forgot to add the escaped double quotes of the original file. I found a solution on another post. +1 for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You want `read_csv()`'s [`quotechar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) parameter:

> The character used to denote the start and end of a quoted item. Quoted items can include the delimiter and it will be ignored.

So add `quotechar='"'`.

Comment: I edited the question, the problem wasn't clear enough.